# How to auto start ejabberd in centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos7, ejabberd

I have installed ejabbered from source code into centos 7 it is running fine but now problem is only how to auto start it with system. I have tried startup application, rc.local file method but all failed is there any other way to run ejabbered with system ?

Edit:- 
I download [ejabberd.service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/processone/ejabberd/master/ejabberd.service.template) file and rename it ejabberd.service and copied it to `/etc/systemd/system/` and run this command `systemctl enable ejabberd.service` to enable it but still ejabberd is not running with system.

Comment: Write a `systemd` service file for it.

Comment: can you please explain how to write one ?

Comment: This is widely documented. Search for it, learn, try and come back if you have specific problems.

Comment: CentOS 7 uses [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) and you need service unit instead of an init script. 

A [systemd unit template](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/ejabberd.service.template) is already included in the source tree.

Comment: I used your suggested method but it doesn't work either, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this running using [ejabberd.service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/processone/ejabberd/master/ejabberd.service.template)
Inside this file, I modified the path so **@ctlscriptpath@** was replaced with the actual path of my installation.
I was then able to start and check on the status of the service.
If you have already tried running the service with the original file, you will need to run: *systemctl daemon-reload* before running: *systemctl start ejabberd*

In my case it was: /opt/ejabberd-17.11/bin/ejabberdctl rather than: @ctlscriptpath@/ejabberdctl
**(make sure you change the path in each location!!)**

It is entirely possible there is another way to replace the variable in a more proper way (I didn't find the more proper way in few minutes of googling, I hope to come back to this later.)

Answer (score -2):

On a *nix system, if you want ejabberd to be started as daemon at boot time, copy ejabberd.init from the ’bin’ directory to something like /etc/init.d/ejabberd (depending on your distribution).

Create a system user called ejabberd, give it write access to the directories database/ and logs/, and set that as home; the script will start the server with that user. Then you can call `/etc/inid.d/ejabberd` start as root to start the server.

Comment: Doesn't work this way anymore. Systemd rules the roost now.